# AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'imread', How to solve it?

Tags: python, scipy

I am enrolled in the Deep Learning Nanodegree Program at Udacity and in the third lesson, they told us to try 'style-transfer' pre-trained model to style some images. They told to us install Anaconda and use Conda's virtual environment `file-transfer` for this purposes. I followed instructions very carefully and did everything as they said in lectures and in written text.

- I created a virtual environment, installed required packages and libraries.
- Downloaded the fast-style-transfer-master [from this github repo](https://github.com/lengstrom/fast-style-transfer) in zip format.
- Downloaded the checkpoint `rain-princess.ckpt` [from this link](https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/January/587d1865_rain-princess/rain-princess.ckpt).
- Extracted fast-file-transfer-master.zip in a folder, let's say **DLND**.
- Copied the `rain-princess.ckpt` and my input image in **DLND** folder

After doing above, I got back to Anaconda Prompt, activated `file-transfer` virtual environment and ran the below command:

```
python evaluate.py --checkpoint ./rain-princess.ckpt --in-path ./input_image.jpg --out-path ./output_image.jpg
```

But I am getting this error `AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'imread'`

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**

1. Downloaded and installed `pillow` by using `pip install pillow` command, but it said, I already have this package and I checked the list with `pip list` and yeah, I had it. So, it did not work.
2. Uninstalled scipy and installed the earlier version 1.1.0 by using `pip install scipy==1.1.0`. But, then it said, it is not compatible with Tensorflow, Tensorflow requires scipy v1.4.x.

Please help me, how to solve this error because I am stuck here in my Nanodegree Program and I have to submit the Project really soon. Fast help will be really appreciated.

Comment: From the documentation: "imread is deprecated! imread is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0. Use imageio.imread instead." [https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html]

Comment: I can't, I have not coded the `fast-style-transfer-master`, I downloaded in from the GitHub repo.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to solve my error:

```
conda uninstall scipy pillow
pip uninstall moviepy tensorflow imageio-ffmpeg
conda install scipy-1.1.0 pillow
pip install moviepy==0.2.3.3 tensorflow==1.15.2 imageio-ffmpeg
```

I ran each line of code one by one and it solve my error.